# List databases command

Tags: orientdb

In this link http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Tutorial-Run-the-console.html it reads

> There are some console commands, such as LIST DATABASES or CREATE
>   DATABASE, which you can run while only connected to the server
>   instance. For other commands, however, you must also connect to a
>   database, before they run without error.

However I tried
orientdb> list databases
Not connected to the Server instance. You've to connect to the Server using server's credentials (look at orientdb-*server-config.xml file)

Is the documentation wrong? Do I need to be connected to a database even to list the list of databases?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your case with my ODB server and I can confirm that you have to be connected to an OrientDB Server instance (but not to a Database) to execute commands like **`LIST DATABASES`**. Steps to reproduce:

1. **Connecting to the server:**

   ```
   orientdb> connect remote:localhost root root

   Connecting to remote Server instance [remote:localhost] with user 'root'...OK
   ```
2. **Executing `LIST DATABASES` command:**

   ```
   orientdb {server=remote:localhost/}> list databases

   Found 3 databases:

   * NewDB1 (plocal)
   * NewDB2 (plocal)
   * GratefulDeadConcerts (plocal)
   ```

Maybe in the [OrientDB documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Tutorial-Run-the-console.html) the section

```
orientdb> LIST DATABASES

Found 1 databases:
* GratefulDeadConcerts (plocal)
```

could have been reported wrongly.

Hope to have been helpful

Comment: Hi @Francisco1844, did you have a chance to try my example ? Does it work correctly for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Console is just an interface to communicate to the OrientDB server instance like other interfaces viz. **Web Editor** . So to actually perform commands like `CREATE DATABASE` and `LIST DATABASES` , you atleast need to connect to the server (Not to a particular database however). Therefore it is necessary to connect to the server running otherwise console won't know where to CREATE or LIST databases from.